# C++ unit test timeout in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

Maybe I'm missing something, but is there a way to set an individual timeout per test in Native Unit Test Project in Visual Studio?
 
I'd like my test to stop running after a specified time (so that I don't have to wait eg. an hour if something goes very wrong with the test).

```
TEST_METHOD(TestMethod)
{
    // Test code
}
```

Maybe there's some property to set?

Comment: did you google it? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.timeoutattribute.aspx

Comment: go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532662/how-can-i-increase-the-timeout-for-visual-studio-tests